# MySQL - How to create rows with same id

Tags: mysql, join, rows

I have two tables 'products' and 'specifications'. How can I join these tables together, that if I create a row in 'products' with for example id 6, it will create new row in 'specifications' with same id. Can i do it only with Relations?

Comment: Can you please show us your table structure?

Comment: Unless you create a trigger, you generally need to create both rows separately in your application code. MySQL doesn't have native functionality to auto-create a row in a related table.  Most often, it is handled by application code rather than a trigger, and can be wrapped in a transaction to make it atomic.

Comment: What platform are you working with in your application code? Many platforms and frameworks have recommended ways of managing these relationships.

Comment: I work with Sequel Pro

Comment: As a MySQL client application, okay. But what will you be using to access, manipulate, and display this data for end users - as in PHP, Ruby on Rails, etc?

Comment: But if this can't be done in MySQL i will do it right in app as you say.